# java how to delay time at while grammar

Tags: java, while-loop, delay

While grammar is infinitely repeat when if condition not meeted.

What I want is delay that between start of while grammar and finish of while grammar.

example,

**want code.java**

```
int count = 1, sum = 0;
while (count < 11){
   count ++;
   System.out.println(count);
   //(after 30 seconds...) what i want is this code.
}
```

therefore, i want same output with down code.

1

(after 30 seconds delay..)

2

(after 30 seconds delay..)

...

10

(after 30 seconds delay..)

Please answer. how to delay time between running while grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your program to pause for 30 seconds at the end of each iteration of the loop then you can use `Thread#sleep` for that:

```
int count = 1, sum = 0;
while (count < 11) {
    count ++;
    System.out.println(count);
    Thread.sleep(30000);  // 30 seconds = 30K milliseconds
}
```